# Sync music library between several Ubuntu installations

Tags: sync, music, rhythmbox, banshee

I found some threads about similar topics but not really the same and neither with a solution.

Is there any way to get a music player (Banshee, Rhythmbox) to synchronize their music library with another computer? That means play counts, playlists, last played, last modified etc.?

For example: I hear most time music at home with my desktop pc. When I'm on the road and want to play music from my laptop, I want to have the same "last played" song from my desktop and so on.

Is there any solution for this?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: maybe placing the relevant files in a dropbox or owncloud works...

Comment: the problem is, that banshee doesn't save those information to the mp3 file. in earlier versions it was possible to force banshee to save it to the file, but my version 2.6.2 doesn't has this option in the menu anymore ...

Comment: I don't use banshee, but I guess it has to store these information somwhere... maybe some config file or similar?

Answer (score 0):

I sync my rhythmbox databse and my music folder using syncthing. The database is stored in

```
 .local/share/rhythmbox
```

I sync the entire folder. The important thing is to set one computer as master, i.e. tick the "Sent only folder" option. For me this is my laptop at home. My other computers are 'receive only'. This means that the all changes on my laptop, including play counts, ratings and playlists, will be transferred to my other computers, but not visa verse. This set up prevents corruption of the database in case the database is changed at two computers before syncing.

This is the best I could come up with. I wish they would develop a proper database sync option for rhythmbox. Given that it is the standard music player on many linux desktop distributions, it receives remarkably little development.